# Twisted Python pause/postpone reactor

Tags: python, twisted, reactor

I'm pretty new to twisted, I have an HTTP client that queries a server that has rate limit, when I hit this limit the server responds with HTTP 204, so when I'm handling the response I'm doing probably something nasty, like this:

```
def handleResponse(r, ip):
if r.code == 204:
    print 'Got 204, sleeping'
    time.sleep(120)
    return None
else:
    jsonmap[ip] = ''
    whenFinished = twisted.internet.defer.Deferred()
    r.deliverBody(PrinterClient(whenFinished, ip))
    return whenFinished
```

I'm doing this because I want to pause all the tasks.

Following there are 2 behaviours that I've in my mind, either re-run the tasks that hit 204 afterwards in the same execution (don't know if it's possible) or just log the errors and re-run them afterwards in another execution of the program. Another problem that may raise is that I've set a timeout on the connection in order to cancel the deferred after a pre-defined amount of time (see the code below) if there's no response from the server

```
timeoutCall = reactor.callLater(60, d.cancel)
def completed(passthrough):
    if timeoutCall.active():
        timeoutCall.cancel()
    return passthrough
d.addCallback(handleResponse, ip)
d.addErrback(handleError, ip)
d.addBoth(completed)
```

Another problem that I may encounter is that if I'm sleeping I may hit this timeout and all my requests will be cancelled.

I hope that I've been enough precise.
Thank you in advance.

Jeppo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `time.sleep(20)` in any Twisted-based code.  This violates basic assumptions that any other Twisted-based code that you might be using makes.

Instead, if want to delay something by *N* seconds, use `reactor.callLater(N, someFunction)`.

Once you remove the `sleep` calls from your program, the problem of unrelated timeouts being hit just because you've stopped the reactor from processing events will go away.

Comment: `reactor.callLater` is good insofar as it is; however, how do you get a deferred to pause execution for a few seconds. As in, within a deferred execution, how do I get the `time.sleep(20)` behaviour!

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  Deferreds do not execute.  They are an API for a result that may not yet be available.

Comment: Okay, that's great. It's an API for a result that may not be available yet. Got it. So, if you're writing a deferred, and within the deferred you have to pause for a few seconds SO THAT you can get that future value correctly. You must pause. Otherwise the future value will be wrong.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this thread, it's imperative that you never call `time.sleep(...)`; however, it is possible to create a `Deferred` that does nothing but sleep... which you can use to compose delays into a deferred chain:

```
   def make_delay_deferred(seconds, result=None):
       d = Deferred()
       reactor.callLater(seconds, d.callback, result)
       return d
```